# Javascript Object and Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have item array and it has 2 items as objects like this:

```
var item = [{
         name: "audi",
         body: "s1",
         type: "cedan",
         price: 10,
         color: "red",
         size: "large",
         shape: "circle"
     }, {
         name: "bmw",
         body: "x1",
         type: "suv",
         price: 20,
         color: "blue",
         size: "medium",
         shape: "square"
     }];
```

how can i generate the following arrays from the item array, i mean if i add new item to item array i want it to be included to the new arrays below automaticlay

```
var name = ["audi","bmw"];
var body = ["s1","x1"];
var color = ["red","blue"];
var size = ["large","medium"];
var shape = ["square","circle"];
var type = ["cedan","suv"];
var price = [10,20];
```

Comment: Are you looking for a map of keys and values as array of values for each of those keys?

Comment: Yes but without repeating the values in the new arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to generate a map of keys and values as array of values for each of those keys, then try

```
var output = {};
item.forEach(function(val){
  Object.keys(val).forEach(function(key){
    output[key] = output[key] || [];
    if( output[key].indexOf(val[key]) == -1 )
    {
      output[key].push(val[key]);
    }
  });
});
```

Now you can fetch the array of values as you like

```
var names = output["name"];
```

Comment: if i have 10 items in item array with same name for some values , then how can i avoid repeation?

Comment: @ahmda before pushing to array you can check whether it already exists or not. Check updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), *The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.*

```js
var item = [{
  name: "audi",
  body: "s1",
  type: "cedan",
  price: 10,
  color: "red",
  size: "large",
  shape: "circle"
}, {
  name: "bmw",
  body: "x1",
  type: "suv",
  price: 20,
  color: "blue",
  size: "medium",
  shape: "square"
}];
var getArrByName = function(arr, key) {
  return arr.map(function(item) {
    return item[key];
  })
};

var name = getArrByName(item, 'name');
var body = getArrByName(item, 'body');
var color = getArrByName(item, 'color');
var size = getArrByName(item, 'size');
var shape = getArrByName(item, 'shape');
var type = getArrByName(item, 'type');
var price = getArrByName(item, 'price');
console.log(JSON.stringify(name));
console.log(JSON.stringify(body));
console.log(JSON.stringify(color));
console.log(JSON.stringify(size));
console.log(JSON.stringify(shape));
console.log(JSON.stringify(type));
console.log(JSON.stringify(price));
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//a utility
var prop = key => obj => obj == null? void 0: obj[key];

var name = item.map( prop('name') );
var body = item.map( prop('body') );
//...
```

or

```
var output = {};
Object.keys(item[0]).forEach(k => {
    output[k] = item.map( prop(k) );
});
```

or

```
var output = item.reduce((out, obj)=>{
    for(var k in obj)
        (out[k] || (out[k] = [])).push(obj[k]);
    return out;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = item.map(function(el){return el.name}).filter(function(el,pos,arr){return arr.indexOf(el)=== pos});
```

Gets you all the names without duplicates. You can do the same for the other attributes you need.

Comment: if i have 10 items in item array with same name for some values , then  how can i avoid repeation?

Comment: updated answer with filter to remove duplicates. I prefer one-liners

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your list of cars and the lists of prices, names etc. in some common code such as a class.

It would be something like this:

```
class Cars {

    constructor() {
        this.carList = [];
        this.nameList = [];
        this.priceList = [];
    }

    addCar(newName, newPrice) {
        this.carList.push({name: newName, price: newPrice});
        this.nameList.push(name);
        this.priceList.push(price);
    }

    getCar(position) {
        return this.carList[position];
    }

    getNames() {
        return this.nameList;
    }

    getPrices() {
        return this.priceList;
    }
}

var someCars = new Cars();

someCars.addCar("audi", 10);
someCars.addCar("bmw", 20);

var carNames = someCars.getNames();
var carPrices = someCars.getPrices();
```

It's unclear whether you want the list of all names (and so on) or just the list of unique names.  This code gives you all names.